# Error while running the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As i have migrated my rails 3.0.0 project to 3.1.0, i have made all the changes as given in this tutorial http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1 except to include the asset pipelining. Everything got installed fine but when i run the server i'm getting the below error.

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:1234
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/vikas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:31:in `alias_method': undefined method `render' for module `ActionView::Rendering' (NameError)
from /home/vikas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:31:in `alias_method_chain'
from /home/vikas/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/PARAS6/vendor/plugins/active_scaffold/lib/active_scaffold/extensions/action_view_rendering.rb:95:in `<module:Rendering>'
from /home/vikas/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/PARAS6/vendor/plugins/active_scaffold/lib/active_scaffold/extensions/action_view_rendering.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
```

Please anyone help me out, suggest me what changes should i make. Thanks in advance

Comment: Start by investigating this error:  `undefined method 'render' for module 'ActionView::Rendering' (NameError)`

Comment: @jcm    i have been trying for the same but nothing helped, so finally i ended up here

Comment: show us the source code, github ?

Comment: @astropanic  https://gist.github.com/vikky-a2/7464345    this is my file i have included please verify it

Comment: show us your complete source code

Comment: complete source code in the sense??? tell me exactly what else should i view... @astropanic

Comment: simply show us your project on github.com not only a pastie of one file

Comment: @astropanic brother this is not a small project to paste it in github, it includes some hundreds of views and much more supporting files.

Comment: so what ? I don't a wizzard to think about a solution without seeing the code, but my first guess is activescaffold gem incompatibility...

Comment: @VIKKY have a look here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/activescaffold/QnHmN7Uc8DE

Comment: @VIKKY You don't need to copy-paste anything.  If you're using Git it shouldn't matter if the project is small or large.  Unless of course there's some sensitive code that you don't want to expose.